# while loop running for every digit/character from input

Tags: c++

Hey guys beginner in C++ and coding in general. I am currently making a tictactoe program. For the part of the program I am validating user input. Since it is a 3x3 table, I want to make sure their input is an integer and that they choose a number between 1~9.

To do this I wrote

```
//Validating user input
void move() {
  std::cout << "It's Player" << player << "'s turn!\n";

  while(!(std::cin >> position)){
    std::cout << "Please choose a NUMBER between 1~9!\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();
  }

  while(position < 1 || position > 9){
    std::cout << "Please choose a number BETWEEN 1~9!\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();
  }
  
  while(board[position - 1] != " ") {
    std::cout << "Already filled please choose another number between 1~9!\n";
    std::cin >> position;
  }
}
```

It works but for some reason when I put in an input like 10, it would print Please choose a number BETWEEN 1~9! twice (for each digit) and if I input in for example "apple" it would print Please choose a NUMBER between 1~9! four times (for each character). How do i make it just print out the statement once?

Thank you!

Comment: under `cctype` header, there is a function `isdigit(p)` that checks if p is a digit or not.

Comment: What is the type of `position`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain to you the problem. It is a little bit subtle and not that easy to understand. Both other answers adress only the obvious part.

Then, let us first recap that:

The boolean condition in the `while` statement is loop invariant. Meaning, it will not be modified within the loop. Whatever it was before the loop, will be the same after the loop body has been executed. The condition will never change.

---

So, for the case where you enter a wrong number:

- If the input number is correct (1..9) and the `while` statement starts to evaluate the boolean expression, it will be false in this case and the loop will not be entered.
- If the number is out of your selected bounds (<1 or >9), then the boolean condition is true. The while loop starts, but the condition relevant variable will not be changed in the loop boody and hence, the boolean expression is always true. The loop will run forever.

Additionally, and now comes the answer to your first question, the following will happen:

1. The text "Please choose a number BETWEEN 1~9!\n" will be shown (first time)
2. `clear` will be called for `std::cin`. The failbit was not set, but anyway. This does not harm
3. The `ignore` function is an unformatted input function. It will actively read the next character from the input buffer, which is the end of line `'\n' character.
4. We enter again the while statement. The condition is still true (position was not modified in the loop body), and we enter the loop again.
5. The text "Please choose a number BETWEEN 1~9!\n" will be shown (second time)
6. `clear` will be called for `std::cin`. The failbit was not set, but anyway. This does not harm
7. The `ignore` function is a formatted input function. It will actively read the next character from the input buffer. But there is none. So it will wait until a key is pressed. For example "enter". After that, it would go back to number 5.

By the way. If you would now enter "abc" then you would see the text 4 times for a,b,c and enter.

So, please remember: [ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) is an input function!

---

Next. It is important to understand, that if you enter an unexpected value, like "apple" instead of "3", the formatted input function `>>` can do no conversion and sets the failbit. It will also not extract further wrong characters from the input stream (`std::cin`is a buffered stream). The characters that could not be converted are still in the buffer and wil be read next time.

Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) about formatted/unformatted input. And especially read about the extraction operatpr `>>` [here.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

There you can read the following:

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), zero is written to value and failbit is set.

OK, understood. Then, what is going on here, if you enter "abc". Basically, the same as above.

1. Enter abc
2. The boolean condition `!(std::cin >> position)`will be evaluated to true, because an 'a' was read and cannot be converted to a number.
3. The `std::cin`'s failbit will be set. The variable `position`will be set to 0.
4. "Please choose a NUMBER between 1~9!\n" will be shown
5. The failbit will be reset
6. `Ignore` will extract exactly the **one** wrong character and discard it
7. std::cin >> position`` will be called again and extract the next wrong character 'b'. 3., 4., 5., 6. will be done again. Until the last charcter in the buffer, the newline '\n' will be extracted. Then you may enter the next number.

The fix for that problem is simple:

`ignore` has a parameter, where you can specify, how many characters shall be ignored. So, not only one, but all until the end of line.

You should write:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This will ignore **all** bad input.

And to fix your whole program, you could write at the top:

```
    while (!(std::cin >> position) or (position < 1 ) or ( position > 9)) {
        std::cout << "Please choose a NUMBER between 1~9!\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

```
while(position < 1 || position > 9){
```

This `while` loop will continue running as long as `position` is less than 1 or greater than 9, that's what this says.

But there's nothing in the while loop itself that changes the value of `position`. For that simple reason, if `position`'s value at this point is outside of the range of 1-9, this `while` loop will execute forever.

You always need to keep in mind The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do. Here, you told your computer to execute this while loop as long as `position` is less than 1 or greater than 9, so this is what your computer will do until this is no longer the case.

Comment: This explains the endless loop, but  does not answer the OPs question, why he sees his output text 2 times in case of a wrong number and times the length of the bad input for the first while. The explanation of the function `ignore` would have been more appropriate. Anyway. It does not matter

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as this. With this you run your while loop ones for every input. Until you get the value as you like. If the value is as you wish, you get out of the loop with `break`

```
std::cout << "Please choose a NUMBER between 1~9!\n";
  while(std::cin >> position){
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();

    if(position < 1 || position > 9){
        std::cout << "Please choose a number BETWEEN 1~9!\n";
    }else{
        break;
    }
  }
```